# Does Android Java support primitive type parameter for generic types?

Tags: java, android, generics

Today I was looking at the following piece of Android source code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/animation/IntArrayEvaluator.java

The type is declared as:

```
public class IntArrayEvaluator implements TypeEvaluator<int[]>
```

My understanding of Java generics is that primitive types and arrays are not supported.

Am I correct in that understanding?

If I am correct is this something unique to Android's implementation of Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are supported because internally one object will be created in Heap for all Primitive array as wrapper type.

but primitive types are not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not correct. `int[]` is allowed as a type parameter in both Android and standard Java. This is because `int[]` is a reference type. `int`, on the other hand, is a primitive type and is not allowed as a type parameter in either.

Answer (score 1):

`int[]` is a reference type, and so can be used as a generic type parameter; this is not the same thing as the primitive `int` type. There is nothing peculiar to Android about this.